# Avoid simplification in apply()

Tags: r, apply

Pretty simple question.

> Is there a way to avoid simplification in `apply()`?

I need to do it because I have an `apply` which can sometimes simplify (and it does it) and sometimes not, thus creating different data structures depending on the input, so I want to avoid it altogether.

I need either something similar to `SIMPLIFY = FALSE` in `mapply()` or a mechanism to control output as the one in `vapply()`.

---

Simple reproducible example:

```
mimat <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), nrow = 2)
mimat2 <- matrix(c(3,2,3,4,5,6), nrow = 2)

apply(mimat, MARGIN = 2, function(x) { 
                              if (is.element(el = 1, x)) return(c(0,1))
                              else return(c(1,2,3))
      })
```

If the `apply()` is applied to `mimat` it outputs a list, whereas if it is applied to `mimat2` it outputs a matrix.

Comment: You should provide an example. You can look here for a possible solution maybe: https://purrr.tidyverse.org/

Comment: Short answer: no, there isn't. The usage of `apply` with functions that might return variable length vectors is dangerous. Much better a `for` loop (or coercing your matrix to a data.frame and then call `lapply` if feasable).

Comment: You could just wrap your return vectors in `list` like so: `return(list(c(0,1)))` and then you will always get a list out.

Comment: @JohnPaul If you do that you get a list of lists, it is something, but still not what I was looking for. Anyway I think I will just avoid the use of `apply()`.

Answer (score 3):

R4.1.0 added a `simplify` argument to `apply()` on [2021-03-06](https://developer.r-project.org/blosxom.cgi/R-devel/NEWS/2021/03/06#n2021-03-06).

With older versions of R, the best option is probably

```r
lapply(seq_len(dim(minat)[2]), YourFunction)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for your purpose functions from `purrr` package might be more suitable as the output is almost known beforehand. And if they couldn't match the output to the data structure they are supposed to return, they throw and error (or die trying as the documentation put it).

For example `map` function always returns a list, whereas its variation `map_dbl`, `map_lgl` and etc each returns a vector of the indicated type.

There is another function called `modify` in this family that preserves the structure of the input data (row numbers and col numbers) and don't alter the data structure, however it is said in the documentation that

> Since the transformation can alter the structure of the input; it's
> your responsibility to ensure that the transformation produces a valid
> output. For example, if you're modifying a data frame, .f must
> preserve the length of the input.

In your first example when you apply your anonymous function to `mimat` the result has different lengths so it is not possible to return a matrix or a data frame as I can try it with `map` to get the same result whereas `modify` fails to preserve the data structure of the input:

```
library(purrr)

map(as.data.frame(mimat), function(x) { 
  if (is.element(el = 1, x)) return(c(0,1))
  else return(c(1,2,3))
})

$V1
[1] 0 1

$V2
[1] 1 2 3

$V3
[1] 1 2 3

modify(as.data.frame(mimat), function(x) { 
  if (is.element(el = 1, x)) return(c(0,1))
  else return(c(1,2,3))
})

> Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c(1, 2, 3)) :   
> replacement has 3 rows, data has 2
```

But in case of your second matrix `mimat2` the output of the function has rows of equal lengths so it is possible to make use of a `map` variation called `map_dfc` to col bind the output. As the `modify` again fails cause the output data structure is different from the output:

```
map_dfc(as.data.frame(mimat2), function(x) { 
  if (is.element(el = 1, x)) return(c(0,1))
  else return(c(1,2,3))
})

# A tibble: 3 x 3
     V1    V2    V3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1
2     2     2     2
3     3     3     3

modify(as.data.frame(mimat2), function(x) { 
  if (is.element(el = 1, x)) return(c(0,1))
  else return(c(1,2,3))
})

Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c(1, 2, 3)) : 
  replacement has 3 rows, data has 2
```

I had to transform them to data frame as otherwise they are considered as a vector and the function is applied on every element instead of just columns.
This brief explanation may not get you to what you wanted but I hope it just serves as an introduction to some other functions with fixed outputs.
In a nutshell it only boils down to the function you apply on your data structure that has to transform the data in a way that makes it possible to preserve the data structure.